# alter $_POST data of radio select option

Tags: php, jquery, html, post, radio-group

So I have a Radio button group, like so:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Now if I just submit the for I get this $_POST (Note I have multiple Radio group questions)

```
Array
(
    [radio-choice-1] => choice-1
    [radio-choice-2] => choice-4
    [radio-choice-3] => choice-2
    [submit] => submit
    [PHPSESSID] => 11111111111111111
)
```

How Can I restructure the HTML or $_POST data before submission to make it look like this:

```
Array
(
    [type-1] => radio-choice-1
    [answer-1] => choice-1
    [type-2] => radio-choice-2
    [answer-2] => choice-4
    [type-3] => radio-choice-3
    [answer-3] => choice-2
    [submit] => submit
    [PHPSESSID] => 11111111111111111
)
```

Maybe jQuery as an option?

Comment: Why would you want to restructure it before submit and not after? Better to do this on the server side. Why do you use choice-X as value and not just the numeric value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it post submission, the code below should work if you keep your original naming conventions.

```
$postValues = $_POST;
$altered = Array();
$unaltered = Array();

foreach ($postValues as $key => $val) {

  if ( FALSE !== stripos($key, 'radio-choice-') ) {

    $num = explode('-', $key);
    $num = $num[2];
    $altered['type-'.$num] = $key;
    $altered['answer-'.$num] = $value;

  } else {

    $unAltered[$key] = $value;

  }  

}

$manipulatedPOSTData = array_merge($altered, $unAltered);

// Keep doing what you intended
```

Comment: That would work too, if he wanted to do it on the server side. +1

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a form that you are submitting?

If you want to add finer control over what gets posted, you can do one of two things:

1) add hidden variables

or

2) use jQuery .post() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead of doing a normal form submission.

Personally, I think the first of the two is simplest:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="hidden" name="type-1" value="radio-choice-1" />
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="answer-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

            <input type="radio" name="answer-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

            <input type="radio" name="answer-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

            <input type="radio" name="answer-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

By changing the name of the radio ground to answer-1 and adding a hidden variable, that should meet your requirements (do the same for your other radio elements).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid client side elaboration if you can.

Otherwise use [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and hand code what you need. but it's harder.